# github flow - the proper way for multiple env

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I know it's been asked many times, but I'd still appreciate the answer again here with some explanations.

So I understand that Github flow just tells you to use `master` and `feature` branches.

As soon as we merge something into `master`, the production server gets updated. What if I want to have `staging` environment as well ? how does Github workflow deal with this ? does it say that when something gets merged into `feature/*` branch, it updates the staging environment ? but if that's so, while having multiple feature branches, we can't have 1 staging environment, which means each feature branch has its own isolated staging environment where the other feature branches' codes don't end up. In any way, if that's the case, we can't do the proper QA testing to test all the work done by multiple feature branches.

Any idea what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend reading thoroughly https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/ (GitHub flow is a subset of TBD) as there are some other options to TBD workflow that may be relevant, i.e. use of release branches.

> As soon as we merge something into master, the production server gets updated.

This is not necessarily true and I think your confusion arises from this statement. Scenario I recommend (although there is no single approach here) is to have a separate repository for deployments. So you have repositories for your actual code and another Git repository for deployment (GitOps way).

Then you have some sort of routing logic between different environments defined by your business rules. In the end of a day the state of your environments should be reflected in the deployment repository. There are tools that automate different parts of the process (disclaimer: I'm working on one of them - Reliza Hub).

The important bit here is that a particular commit from your master branch gets first deployed to test or staging, then tests are done exactly on that code and only then it gets deployed to the next environment and eventually to production. So you only move to production what was previously seen in other environments. And the main QA activity is done on the code merged into master.

Now, regarding feature branches - those are meant to be short-lived. Mostly they should be covered by automated tests. In some cases (for high-impact changes), it makes sense to spin up a short-lived environment that would host code from a feature branch and do some manual testing on this environment. This last approach is quite popular at the moment, but tooling is heavily customized - usually it takes time to set this up properly.

Finally, if you use release branches it may make sense to have more than one set of test, staging, etc environments. This depends on the size and compliance requirements for your project.